# AWS IoT SDK Device SDK for C#

Tags: c#, aws-iot

I couldn't find an official AWS IoT Device SDK for C#/.NET (only c++, java, javascript and python), yet we need to build a client device application that connects to the AWS IoT and utilizes its capabilities (more than just MQTT which we did find) like Device Shadows.

Did anyone encounter this issue and find a solution?

Comment: What about [AmazonIoTClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/IoT/TIoTClient.html) ?

Comment: This is the service-side SDK, I believe it will not provide the capabilities we need like the Device Shadow (on device side)